# What does 12CC refer to when talking about voltage?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical, valves, electronics, connections

Is it 12V with a connector?
For example in the data sheet here: https://www.hydraulicmegastore.com/product/vcf12nc12cc/

Is this related in any way? (A DMP-12CC connector cable)
https://www.monacor.com/products/pa-technology/mixers-and-players/insertion-modules/dmp-12cc/

Any resources for this would be really helpful

Answer (score 3):

Italian "corrente continua" is Direct Current.

Comment: So why have "220VDC"?

Comment: @Transistor I'd put it down to a partial translation. Typical Italian solenoid datasheet often use 12CC or 12VCC and for international published datasheet translate to 12VDC. e.g. see this completely different vendor https://www.leaderhydraulics.com/product/stocklist-bosch-rexroth-solenoid-coil-r932000757-s2-ce-12vcc/

Answer (score 0):

Always link to the [datasheet](https://www.hydraulicmegastore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/TAEFA_EN-Normal-closed_page_001.png) - not to catalog pages.

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from the datasheet.*

According to the datasheet there is no correlation between the "CC" designation and the coil voltage.

The only thing I can think of is that the 12CC and 24CC coils will run on both AC and DC and the CC means something in another language.

Answer (score 0):

**Meaning of CC**

According to [this source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/114916/what-is-cv-cc-in-power-supplies), "CC" stands for Constant Current which is usually related to the behavior of power supplies on load. When you use a power supply you usually set the desired voltage and the maximum current. When you connect the load two things can happen:

- The load requires more current than the maximum you set. The power supply becomes a current source: the current is limited to what you set and voltage drops accordingly, that's "CC".
- The load requires at most the maximum current you set. The power supply becomes a voltage source, that's Constant Voltage or "CV".

**Meaning of VDC**

According to [this source](https://www.gridpoint.com/blog/vdc-voltage-what-is-vdc-voltage/):

- "VDC" (Volts Direct Current) is the voltage of a direct current (DC) circuit.
- "VAC" (Volts Alternating Current) is a measure of the strength of the alternating electric field that drives the flow of electrons in AC electrical systems. Unlike DC (Direct Current) voltage, which remains constant, VAC fluctuates sinusoidally, reversing direction periodically at a fixed frequency, typically 50 or 60 Hertz. The peak voltage of an AC waveform is measured in volts and is the maximum voltage that can be achieved during each cycle.

Comment: Since you directly quoted Vlad's answer, you should credit him with the quote.

Comment: Some solenoid characteristic behavior and driver strategies here - https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu578/tidu578.pdf?ts=1697438032346&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F